# How to access the Windows 7 shared folders

Tags: 12.04, networking, windows-7, shared-folders

I'm a little new to Ubuntu, but I'm lovin' it so far :)

I have Ubuntu 12.04 installed om my older desktop and connected with a wire.
My (newer) laptop has windows 7 running and has all my music. I'd like to access the music and play it on the desktop.

This should be possible since it's a shared folder in Windows 7, but I have no clue how to access these files from my Linux machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you open your `Home Folder` you can access your Network by clicking on `Browse Network` in the bottom left corner. From there you can access all your shared folders. I access my Desktop running Windows 8 like this. :)

[image]

Comment: @MrSeed Do you need to make any changes to the Win 7 machine as well? I've enabled sharing on it but Ubuntu cannot seem to logon. It repeatedly asks for the login but no errors - nothing.